# Product of $n$ consecutive prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How to prove that, the product of $n$ consecutive primes starting from $2$ and $n\geq 5$, is greater than the cube of $(n+1)$th prime?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you know, we have that between a prime $p$ and $2p$ there is another prime $q$. This is Bertrand's postulate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

So for the $n$th prime $p_n$ we then have that $p_{n+1}<2p_n$.

Now we suppose $(2p_n)^2>p_{n+1}^2>2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot\dotso\cdot p_n$

We can cancel some factors and estimate:

$p_n>2p_{n-1}$, which contradicts that $p_{n-1}<p_n<2p_{n-1}$.